# get renderHook's result more than once

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I got a test which calls `renderHook` like this:

```
const { result } = renderHook(() => useMyHook(useDispatch()), wrapper);
```

It's all good and working, and I can get the return value in `result.current`..

It seems like I can't call another hook with `renderHook`.. If I do the exact same thing, then it says that `result` is already defined. If I change the name to something else, like "res", it says that res is undefined, like it's only working for the specific name "result".

So how can I call it more than one time?

Answer (score 1):

I'm might be off, but it looks like you are calling something like this:

```
const { result } = renderHook(() => useMyHook(useDispatch()), wrapper);
const { result } = renderHook(() => useMyHook(useDispatch()), wrapper);
```

In which case you are trying to redefine variable `result`

You can scope it like this:

```
{
  // 1st time
  const { result } = renderHook(() => useMyHook(useDispatch()), wrapper);
  // validate result of creating 1st hook in here
}
{
  // 2nd time
  const { result } = renderHook(() => useMyHook(useDispatch()), wrapper);
  // validate result of creating 2nd hook in here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you should only be testing one hook per test, perhaps you have to unmount the current component first:

```
const { result, unmount } = renderHook(() => useMyHook(useDispatch()), wrapper);

// ... do what you need with result

unmount();

// call your new hook...
const { result } = renderHook(() => useNewHook(useDispatch()), wrapper);
```

Comment: Try with cleanup instead of unmount